# Resolve nested promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I would like to know how I can deal with parameter nested promise.

I have this kind of code :

```
'use strict';

function fetchData(tableName) {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (tableName === 'tableName2') {
      setTimeout(reject, 200, tableName);
    } else {
      setTimeout(resolve, 200, tableName);
    }
  });
}

function notifyUser(data) {
  console.log(data); // get only undefined 3 times
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 200, data);
  });
}

let cont = { fail: () => '', success: () => console.log };
function verifyAndNotify(context) {
  let actions = [];
  ['tableName1','tableName2','tableName3'].map(tableName => {
    actions.push(notifyUser(fetchData(tableName))); // how to deal with this???
  });

  Promise.all(actions)
    .then(success => {
      console.log(`All is ok ${success}`);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(`error with: ${error}`);
      errors.push(error);
    });

  if (errors.lenght > 0) {
    return context.fail(`Errors: ${errors}`);
  } else {
    return context.success(`Success`);
  }
}

verifyAndNotify(cont);
```

The problem is I need to resolve the param before giving it to the method. I probably mix few things I very bad at JS.

I would like to notify the user with each tableName and I would like to raise an error if one the "table" actions failed (fetching data or notify).

**EDIT 1:**

First working version after comments and answer:

```
'use strict';

function fetchData(tableName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (tableName === 'tableName2') {
      setTimeout(reject, 200, tableName);
    } else {
      setTimeout(resolve, 200, tableName);
    }
  });
}

function notifyUser(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 200, data);
  });
}

const cont = { fail: (msg) => console.log('' + msg), done: (msg) => console.log('' + msg) };
function verifyAndNotify(context) {
  const errors = [];
  const actions = ['tableName1', 'tableName2', 'tableName3'].map(tableName =>
    fetchData(tableName).then(notifyUser).catch(error => {errors.push(error);}));

  Promise.all(actions)
    .then(success => {
      if (errors.length) throw errors;
      else {
        context.done(`Success ${success}`);
      }
    }).catch(errors => {
      context.fail(`Errors: ${errors}`);
    });
}

verifyAndNotify(cont);
```

Comment: your functions should **return** promises, but you just create promise, so, in `actions` you have three undefined, instead promises

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) `verifyAndNotify()` can't return anything but a Promise. And `errors` will not only be empty (at the time you check its length) it's not even defined in your code.

Comment: And why do you use an exception to propagate that `tableName === 'tableName2'`? Is this really an Error? Next, `Promise.all()` will be rejected and abort execution as soon as the first rejected Promise arrives. Your `catch()` will only log the first error that happened; and push it into `errors`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Grundy said, the first problem is that your functions need to return the promises (`return new Promise ...`).

As far as your actions list goes, you might be looking to map your array to an array of promises:

```
const actions = ['tableName1', 'tableName2', 'tableName3'].map(tableName =>
    fetchData(tableName).then(notifyUser));
```

Also, you appear to want a list of each promise that had an error, in which case you'll want to add a `catch` to each action promise because `Promise.all` rejects as soon as one action rejects.  For example:

```
const errors = [];
const actions = ['tableName1', 'tableName2', 'tableName3'].map(tableName =>
    fetchData(tableName).then(notifyUser).catch(errors.push));
Promise.all(actions)
    .then(success => {
        if (errors.length) throw errors;
        else {
            console.log(`All is ok ${success}`);
            context.done(`Success`);
        }
    }).catch(errors => {
        context.fail(`Errors: ${errors}`);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had an error with the error push `TypeError: Array.prototype.push called on null or undefined` so I changed it a little bit and posted the edited version in the question.